# Which version of Unity use with a full app asset?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I want to try an asset that is a template pack (a full app) that I want to modify to publish with the content that I like.

In the asset store says that "original unity version is 2019.4.34 or higher".

The app comes integrated with UnityAds and UnityApp Purchase and admob. I want to try those to see how the work, so my question is:

Should I work with unity 2019 or with unity 2021?

In one hand I'm worried about unity 2021 should lead to errors that I don't understand to solve.

In the other hand in the reviews I saw that old reviews are all very nice but newer says the had problems with Admob. I'm not using admob but I want to try unity ads and IAP.

So if I use unity 2019 these features will work or they are not working anymore?

Comment: Try 2021 and see if it works / if a lot of API maybe changed and needs to be fixed ... you can still fallback to 2019 if it doesn't work / is too much effort to fix for 2021

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Unity 2019 or Unity 2021 to work with the template pack but keep in mind that the last version of Unity which is **2021** may have some bugs fixed and may work better with the pack you have purchased. If you don't use admob, Unity 2021 may be the better option. Also, its likely taht their will  be further updates that will resolve admob related issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).